# MySQL Full Text Search not working with left join

Tags: mysql, sql, match-against

I am using full text search on a table , and left joining it with a table from a different DB.
The table (`table1`) has a full-text index defined on the column `name`.

when I try using full text search the following query DOES NOT WORK:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t2.url
FROM `db1`.table1 t1
LEFT JOIN `db2`.table2 t2
ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
WHERE t2.column1 IS NOT NULL
AND MATCH (t1.name) AGAINST ('searchString' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

but when using it without the left join the query WORKS:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM `db1`.table1 t1
WHERE MATCH (t1.name) AGAINST ('searchString' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

NOTE : I cannot use `LIKE %searchString%`, instead of `match-against` for performance issues.

Is there a way of using full text search and left join in the same query?

EDIT: it seems that the problem is somehow related to the fact that both tables are not in the same db.  when trying to do the same query with two tables from the same db, it works. any idea why this might happen?

Comment: What happens if you remove t2.column1 IS NOT NULL.

Comment: can you add sample data here

Comment: still doesnt work when removing the IS NOT NULL. 
not getting any error, query is just stuck.

Comment: Hope that the missing ' is juste a typo...

Comment: yes, just a typo. edited, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes We can use Full text search and left join in the same query.

Check example and query. : [Link](http://rextester.com/SFWLS54635)

```
        SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t2.url
        FROM `db1`.table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN `db2`.table2 t2
        ON t1.column1 = t2.column1 and t2.column1 IS NOT NULL
        where MATCH (t1.name) AGAINST ('searchString' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Please let us know, if there in any error.

Comment: thank you for the example!  it seems that the problem is somehow related to the fact that both tables are not in the same db. the query doesn't work with the two tales from different dbs, but when trying to do the same query with two tables from the same db, it works.  
any idea why this might happen?

Comment: I think it may not happen. I checked at here with dummy databases. it works. - reach me @ sujayb7@gmail

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH(t1.name) AGAINST ('searchString' IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI `where t2.column1 is not null` turns the left join into a join.
Left join is all data from first table however when you specify a where clause on the right table (2nd) then you force the query into a join.  This is probably the cause of why the query is not working.  There is no matching data in the 2nd (right) table.